# AJAX + phpmailer errors

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, phpmailer

Getting a 500 Internal Server error on the client side when trying to test with phpmailer.

Based on my knowledge, it's throwing the error due to a misplaced or nonexistent file, but the file is actually there.

Here's a screenshot of the file structure for [the site](http://cl.ly/VI7P) and for [the includes file](http://cl.ly/VHX5)

**PHP**

```
 <?php 

// $email and $message are the data that is being
// posted to this page from our html contact form
// $email = $_POST['email'] ;
// $message = $_POST['message'] ;

// When we unzipped PHPMailer, it unzipped to
// based on where this php file sites, i gave it the following path. 
    // But also tried, '../includes/phpmailer.class.phpmailer.php'
    // and also tried, 'phpmailer.class.phpmailer.php'
require_once("includes/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 587;  
$mail->Username     = "patrick.johnson9@gmail.com";
$mail->Password     = "corner09";

$mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
$mail->AddAddress("im@pbj.me","First Last")

$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via smtp (Gmail), basic";
$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test
$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");      // attachment
$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer_mini.gif"); // attachment

if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
?>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
 // Form submission 
 $("#form-apply").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  // get the form data
   var formData = {
    "name":     $("input[name='name']").val(),
    "email":    $("input[name='email']").val(),
    "message":   $("input[name='message']").val(),
    // "upload":   $("textarea[name='upload']").val()
   };
    console.log(formData);

   $.ajax({
    type: "POST", //define the type of HTTP verb we want to use
    url: "../includes/form-apply.php",
    data: formData, //our data object
    dataType: "json",
    encode: true
   }).done(function(data){ //using the done promise callback

    // log the data to the console so we can see it
    console.log(data);

    if(! data.success){
      if (data.errors.name){
        $("#name").parent().addClass("has-error");
        $(".name-group").append("<div class='help-block'>" + data.errors.name + "</div>");
        // $("#name").attr("placeholder", data.errors.name);
      }

      if(data.errors.email){
        $("#email").parent().addClass("has-error");
        $(".email-group").append("<div class='help-block'>" + data.errors.email + "</div>");
      }

      if(data.errors.subject){
        $("#subject").parent().addClass("has-error");
        $(".subject-group").append("<div class='help-block'>" + data.errors.subject + "</div>");
      }

      if(data.errors.message){
        $("#message").parent().addClass("has-error");
        $(".message-group").append("<div class='help-block'>" + data.errors.message + "</div>");
      }
    } else {
      $(".form-apply").prepend("<div class='alert alert-success'>" + data.message + "</div>")
      $("input, textarea").val("");
    }
   }).fail(function(data){
      $("#form-apply").prepend("<div class='alert alert-danger'>" + data.errors + "</div>");
    console.log(data.errors);
   });
});
```

**HTML** NOTE THIS MODULE IS A PHP INCLUDE CALLED 'CAREER-MODAL.PHP WHICH EXISTS IN THE 'INCLUDES' DIRECTORY.

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title center" id="myModalLabel">Career Application</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="form-apply" role="form" method="POST" action="includes/form-apply.php">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group name-group">
                <label for="name">Full Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name" tabindex="1" required="required">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group email-group">
                <label for="name">Email</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" tabindex="2" required="required">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group .message-group">
            <label for="name">Summary of Background</label>
            <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" tabindex="3" required="required"></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Upload Resume</label>
              <input type="file" name="upload" id="upload" class="form-control" placeholder="No File Chosen" tabindex="4">
          </div>
          <div class="row center">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary" tabindex="4">submit</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the mail code in file _phpmail-form.php_?

Comment: Any 500 error will have a matching entry in your web server's error log. I'd start by looking there